# Determining the FWHM from a distribution in R

Tags: r, model-fitting, fitdistrplus

I have a dataset:

```
 x = c(30, 23, 22, 31, 18, 16, 19, 16, 15, 23, 21, 17, 17, 27, 24, 22, 27, 32, 23, 21, 14, 19, 22, 23, 22, 19, 13, 22, 33, 25, 24, 26, 24, 24, 13, 21, 23, 23, 31, 23, 25, 20, 24, 23, 24, 16, 19, 33, 36, 29, 29, 26, 22, 23, 23, 23, 20, 27, 32, 30, 34, 37, 28, 24, 29, 32, 35, 32, 25, 28, 27, 32, 33, 25, 25, 30, 25, 25, 26, 36, 30, 37, 27, 25, 26, 34, 38, 29, 30, 32, 31, 33, 33, 31, 37, 36, 42, 32, 37, 34, 37, 38, 31, 25, 27, 27, 32, 33, 39, 38, 36, 32, 35, 33, 36, 40, 39, 32, 32, 34, 35, 38, 43, 43, 39, 30, 33, 39, 39, 46, 51, 40, 30, 37, 48, 52, 47, 58, 41, 47, 51, 55, 56, 46, 34, 47, 45, 48, 52, 66, 56, 49, 66, 71, 63, 47, 41, 50, 56, 58, 56, 56, 61, 49, 57, 58, 52, 65, 70, 75, 59, 55, 44, 48, 49, 49, 55, 61, 58, 56, 56, 62, 64, 58, 59, 64, 64, 61, 56, 62, 64, 78, 86, 80, 75, 65, 75, 66, 72, 85, 65, 70, 63, 58, 73, 83, 89, 78, 75, 79, 84, 92, 90, 80, 76, 82, 83, 82, 82, 93, 93, 79, 92, 97, 84, 85, 81, 90, 99, 106, 100, 96, 97, 101, 128, 120, 121, 109, 125, 118, 121, 118, 123, 108, 115, 123, 123, 117, 113, 124, 128, 142, 134, 120, 116, 112, 129, 149, 150, 134, 134, 133, 139, 165, 167, 173, 158, 170, 188, 186, 191, 172, 163, 176, 182, 188, 205, 203, 219, 211, 229, 242, 245, 273, 270, 285, 292, 329, 355, 358, 362, 403, 429, 480, 516, 512, 525, 544, 575, 595, 668, 622, 612, 627, 649, 620, 576, 608, 576, 545, 471, 435, 422, 416, 405, 372, 338, 299, 285, 279, 274, 251, 241, 213, 201, 197, 203, 197, 196, 189, 184, 166, 165, 161, 167, 160, 157, 139, 131, 141, 152, 143, 144, 140, 136, 148, 123, 114, 113, 109, 122, 134, 120, 103, 117, 134, 117, 106, 114, 112, 104, 86, 94, 103, 108, 98, 109, 98, 100, 108, 114, 92, 78, 83, 111, 98, 78, 80, 80, 68, 62, 76, 74, 89, 78, 85, 86, 86, 76, 71, 72, 72, 64, 76, 77, 77, 89, 76, 65, 61, 66, 68, 72, 75, 72, 67, 67, 69, 75, 65, 63, 75, 68, 65, 59, 68, 61, 60, 63, 63, 58, 63, 59, 49, 68, 55, 60, 67, 65, 69, 68, 53, 59, 64, 45, 43, 42, 48, 46, 50, 52, 41, 38, 44, 38, 51, 50, 51, 41, 40, 41, 41, 34, 41, 32, 35, 39, 52, 46, 38, 37, 39, 36, 36, 34, 41, 40, 38, 38, 47, 45, 46, 36, 40, 34, 32, 39, 41, 47, 38, 38, 33, 44, 37, 38, 30, 34, 30, 40, 43, 41, 31, 27, 39, 34, 31, 29, 29, 25, 38, 38, 33, 42, 45, 46, 42, 37, 40, 35, 50, 34, 29, 25, 30, 36, 35, 36, 35, 24, 22, 29, 29, 32, 32, 25, 32, 30, 28, 23, 28, 34, 31, 28, 30, 27, 27, 20, 25, 32, 32, 41, 28, 19, 22, 23, 20, 25, 31, 27, 24, 26, 21, 20, 25, 33, 31, 44, 31, 31, 22, 29, 29, 32, 20, 24, 26, 27, 28, 24, 16, 19, 24, 23, 28, 27, 22, 24, 18, 19, 19, 21, 26, 26, 25, 28, 28, 32, 32, 26, 23, 31, 27, 20, 18, 29, 25, 15, 23, 28, 29)
```

I know the data follows the following distribution, a quadratic background with a cauchy peak:

```
a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 + ex^4 + fx^5 + gx^6 + (A/pi)(gamma/((x-pos)^2 + gamma^2))
```

I am trying to determine the optimum parameters to fit this data in order to find the 'gamma' parameter. This will tell me the FWHM of the distribution. I only know the 'pos' parameter. This is the location of the peak.

Here is a plot of this distribution:

[image: Plot of data values]

I have achieved this in python using the lmfit package but have not found  a way to do this in R yet. I believe it requires the fitdistrplus package but I have had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: you can have a look here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nls.html . You could do domething I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the data sets are a little different, you should be able to use the same recipe as found at [R Find Full width at half maximum for a gausian density distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015410/r-find-full-width-at-half-maximum-for-a-gausian-density-distribution) -- to get FWHM you need a density curve which is the part that's missing:

```
> d <- density(na.omit(x),n=1e4)
> xmax <- d$x[d$y==max(d$y)]
> x1 <- d$x[d$x < xmax][which.min(abs(d$y[d$x < xmax]-max(d$y)/2))]
> x2 <- d$x[d$x > xmax][which.min(abs(d$y[d$x > xmax]-max(d$y)/2))]
> points(c(x1, x2), c(d$y[d$x==x1], d$y[d$x==x2]), col="red")
> (FWHM <- x2-x1)
[1] 43.37897
```

[image: fwhm-density]

Comment: I don't think this will work with my data. This code works by finding half the height of the distribution. As my data sits on a quadratic background it effects what will be seen as the half way point of the peak. The gamma value in my distribution shall be different to the width of the peak at half the height of the total distribution. It shall be the width of the peak at half the height of the peak.