# Calculating FWHM from spectra in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to find a way to calculate the FWHM of a spectra peak using R programming.

The following dataset is used to get one of the peaks:

```
theta <- c(32.1, 32.2, 32.3,32.4,32.5, 32.6, 32.7, 32.8, 32.9, 33.0, 33.1)
intensity <- c(0, 0, 18, 138, 405, 449, 187, 29, 2, 0, 0)
```

Geom_line is the way I chose to plot this. The code used:

```
pacman::p_load(pacman, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, svglite)
DataOne <- data.frame(thetaOne, intensityOne)
view (DataOne)
PlotOne <- ggplot(data = DataOne) +
  geom_line(aes(x = thetaOne, y = intensityOne))
PlotOne
```

My wish is after plotting the spectra I can calculate the Full Width at Half Maximum  of the peaks (the width at half the height of the peak) in each spectrum.
The dataset I use is much bigger than the one provided above. If possible, I would like a function that allowed me to select the region in the x axis that the peak starts and ends.

I found this: [Determining FWHM from a distribution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980903/determining-the-fwhm-from-a-distribution-in-r).
However, it seems outdated, almost 5 years old. Also, I didn't understand what they proposed as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This little function will return a data frame of the x, y co-ordinates of the FWHM given the input x, y values of a peaked curve:

```r
fwhm <- function(x, y) {
  peak <- which.max(y)
  pre  <- seq(peak)
  post <- peak:length(x)
  half <- y[peak]/2
  xvals <- suppressWarnings(c(approx(y[pre], x[pre], xout = half)$y, 
                              approx(y[post], x[post], xout = half)$y))
  
  ss <- which(x > min(xvals) & x < max(xvals))
  data.frame(x = c(min(xvals), x[ss], max(xvals)),
             y = c(half, y[ss], half))
}
```

To use it in your case, we can just do:

```r
half_width <- fwhm(DataOne$thetaOne, DataOne$intensityOne)
```

We can get the x values of our width at half-maximum with:

```r
range(half_width$x)
#> [1] 32.43240 32.68569
```

And plotting it can be done like this:

```r
ggplot(data = DataOne, aes(x = thetaOne, y = intensityOne)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_area(data = half_width, aes(x, y), fill = "red", alpha = 0.3) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! What package should I get to ue that FWHM function? I tried running the code you suggested and I get "Error in fwhm(DataOne$thetaOne, DataOne$intensityOne) : 
  could not find function "fwhm". Thank you!

Comment: @GiovanniSaboia the fwhm function is at the top of my answer. Just run the code I have provided.

Comment: Ok, my bad. It works now.  In case I have more than one peak, how can I select which peak it will calculate the FWHM? For exemple, if I have the following dataset: theta <- c(32.1, 32.2, 32.3,32.4,32.5, 32.6, 32.7, 32.8, 32.9, 33.0, 33.1, 33.2, 33.3, 33.4, 33.5 38, 38.1, 38.2, 38.3, 38.4, 38.5, 38.6, 38.7, 38.8, 38.9, 39)
intensity <- c(0, 0, 18, 138, 405, 449, 187, 29, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 21, 149, 227, 468, 675, 429, 190, 40, 1,0)